# Left navigation bar customization based on user permissions

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, jquery, master-page, navigation

I have to change my left navigation based on specific user permission.

Is that possible without change in masterpage?

I know jQuery is one solution but any other way through we change left navigation.

If no other solution then jQuery is also acceptable.

Answer (score 3):

I think you can! Someone on msdn posted the following:

> Audience Targetting
>
> I'd recommend at dividing your users into SharePoint groups.   You can
>   then use Audience Targeting to set who can or can not see specific
>   links (Site settings > Navigation).  For audience targetting, you
>   target SharePoint groups, AD groups or specific users.  Please
>   remember that Audience Targetting is not a security trimming.
>
> Security Trimming
>
> If you'd like to limit who can see items in the navigation, then
>   SharePoint will manage the navigation that based
>   on the permissions.  You just have to make sure that security is
>   defined properly for each site, list library, document library or any
>   specific item you have in your navigation menu.

so if you put the users into groups and then you can set permissions to that group if they are allowed to certin parts and let sharepoint handle the hiding and showing :)

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepoint2010general/thread/1aabad61-d039-4b05-a86c-8fb854031a67/

Answer (score 0):

Do look into a control called 'SPSecurityTrimmedControl' - [MSDN Ref](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webcontrols.spsecuritytrimmedcontrol.aspx)